# clFFT performance evaluation

Tags: formatting, opencl

I have been  working on performance evaluation of the clFFT library AMD Radeon R7 260x. The CPU is intel xeon inside and OS is centOS.

I have been studying the performance of 2D 16x16 clFFT with different batch modes (Parallel FFTs). I wondered to see the different results obtained from especially event profiling and gettimeofday.

The results of 2D 16x16 clFFT with different batch modes are as following,

**Using EventProfiling:**

```
batch  kernel exec time(us)

   1    320.7
  16    461.1
 256    458.3
 512    537.7
1024    1016.8
```

Here, the *batch* represents the parallel FFTs and the *kernel execution time* represents the execution time in micro seconds.

**Using gettimeofday**

```
batch  HtoD(us)  kernelExecTime(us) DtoH(us)

   1    29653      10850             39227
  16    28313      10786             32474
 256    26995      11167             39672
 512    26145      10773             32273
1024    26856      11948             31060
```

Here, the *batch* represents the parallel FFTs, *H to D* represents data transfer time from host to device, the *kernel exec time* represents the kernel execution time and *D to H* represents the data transfer time from device to host and all are in micro seconds.

(I am sorry as I cant show you the results in good table format, I can not able to add tables here. hope you can read still).
Here are my questions,

1a) Why the kernel times obtained from EventProfiling are completely different from that of gettimeofday?

1b) Here the another question is that, which results are correct?

2) The data (w.r.t size) transfers increases as the batch size increases. Bur from the results of the gettimeofday, the data transfer times either the *H to D* or *D to H* are almost constant instead of growing as the batch size increases from 1 to 1024. Why is that?

```
clFinish( cl_queue);

// Copy data from host to device
gettimeofday(&t_s_gpu1, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer( cl_queue, d_data, CL_TRUE, 0, width*height*batchSize*sizeof(cl_compl_flt), h_src, 0, NULL, &event1);
clFinish( cl_queue);
clWaitForEvents(1, &event1); 
gettimeofday(&t_e_gpu1, NULL);

checkCL( clAmdFftBakePlan( fftPlan, 1, &cl_queue, NULL, NULL) );

clAmdFftSetPlanBatchSize( fftPlan, batchSize );
clFinish( cl_queue);

gettimeofday(&t_s_gpu, NULL);
checkCL( clAmdFftEnqueueTransform( fftPlan, CLFFT_FORWARD, 1, &cl_queue, 0, NULL, &event, &d_data, NULL, NULL) );
clFinish( cl_queue);
clWaitForEvents(1, &event); 
gettimeofday(&t_e_gpu, NULL);

clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);

totaltime=totaltime+time_end - time_start;
clFinish( cl_queue);

// Copy result from device to host

gettimeofday(&t_s_gpu2, NULL);
checkCL( clEnqueueReadBuffer(cl_queue, d_data, CL_TRUE, 0, width*height*batchSize*sizeof(cl_compl_flt), h_res, 0, NULL, &event2));
clFinish( cl_queue);
clWaitForEvents(1, &event2); 
gettimeofday(&t_e_gpu2, NULL);
```

I will be looking for your comments and answers and load of thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to tell just from these figures. But I assume that you are aware of the subtelties related to the fact that tasks are usually *enqueued*, and not necessarily finished until you call `clFinish`. Maybe post some small snippet showing how exactly you do the measurement.

Comment: Thank you Marco. Now, i added the code in the question itself only.